# Cancel/Clear Unity Upload to Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a Unity project and have been using a Firestore Database.

I realised there was a formatting error with the current data in my collection so I saved it to a list, changed it and attempted to reupload to a new collection.

In play mode, I attempted to upload this.  It was a pretty large list.  I stopped play mode and the data did not upload to the Firestore DB.

I basically looped a list and passed the samples to this method.

```
 public void AddSample(Sample sample)
    {
       
        firestore.Collection(_collectionPath).Document().SetAsync(sample);
    }
```

I was receiving an error, when I would reentered play mode

```
 Future with handle 1 still exists though its backing API <<code number here>> is being deleted.
```

This error is no longer appearing. Nothing I upload through the Unity app in Play Mode is appearing in the database.  Uploads from my app build on my phone are working, they are set to a different collection on the same database.  I have not rebuilt the app since attempting the large upload.

I am somewhat new to unity and firebase, and still learning a lot about software development.
I figure large upload is preventing any smaller uploads.  I am hoping there must be some way of clearing the upload / stopping the upload i.e. maybe its working off some cache when reconnected to the internet.

Any advice, information, links etc., would be greatly appreciated.

I tried :

```
 firestore.TerminateAsync();
            firestore.ClearPersistenceAsync();
```

hoping that might clear the upload, no success.

Answer (score 0):

So, for anyone facing a similar concern going forward, it was a simple solution.

I created a new collection for this data but forgot to update my security rule, hence it appeared that app in playmode was failing to upload